# CS50x 2019 pset2: Vigenère does not fully work

Tags: cs50, vigenere

I am currently working on the pset2 of CS50x 2019, specifically on Vigenère. The CS50 Gradebook shows me 93% finished after uploading it to GitHub.

I have already tried some other code snippets that you can find online but they did not seem to work.

Here is the part of my program that creates the ciphertext:

```c
    string k = argv[1];
    // Get the plaintext and print out the ciphertext
    string s = get_string("plaintext: ");
    printf("ciphertext: ");

    // Iterate through plaintext letter by letter
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(s) ; i < n; i++)
    {
        int key = tolower(k[i % strlen(k)]) - 'a';

        // Check if the letter is lowercase, uppercase or neither and print out the rotated character
        if (islower(s[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", (((s[i] - 'a') + key) % 26) + 'a');
        }
        else if (isupper(s[i]))
        {
            printf("%c", (((s[i] - 'A') + key) % 26) + 'A');
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c", s[i]);
        }
    }

    printf("\n");
    return 0;
```

There are some examples in the documentation which you can test out with your code.

The following example does not work with my code:

```
$ ./vigenere bacon
plaintext:  Meet me at the park at eleven am
ciphertext: Negh zf av huf pcfx bt gzrwep oz
```

My output is:

```
$ ./vigenere bacon
plaintext: Meet me at the park at eleven am
ciphertext: Negh ne og tjs qaty bt syfvgb bm
```

As you can see, the first 4 characters are correct but the remaining are not.

Comment: This key is false : int key = tolower(k[i % strlen(k)]) - 'a';  because, when plaintext character is equal to m , k[5%5]= k[0] = b  . So m+b = m+1 = n .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `int key = tolower(k[i % strlen(k)]) - 'a';` is a problem.

From the spec:

> Remember also that every time you encipher a character, you need to
>   move to the next letter of k, the keyword (and wrap around to the
>   beginning of the keyword if you exhaust all of its characters). But if
>   you don’t encipher a character (e.g., a space or a punctuation mark),
>   don’t advance to the next character of k!

The bottom line is: since `plaintext` and `key` run at different "rates" you cannot use the same index (in this case `i`) for both. The program should crawl `plaintext` one character at a time, as is done here. But it needs a separate way to control the character in `key` so you can 1) skip spaces/punctuation and 2) wrap around. Another variable for the `key` index would be one way to solve it. There may be other problems in the code, but this is a fundamental flaw.